# which datatype for resolution

Tags: php, mysql, database, resolution, varchar

Which datatype would fit the most for saving resolution into a database?

For example something like:

> 720x576

I would use a varchar but I am not really sure if that is correct (best practice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 2 integer columns - height and width. Always store atomic data and never mutliple values in a single column.

`unsigned smallint` [should be enough](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) for your purposes.

Comment: so I should create a column for the width value and height value? Thanks